# custom class says its null when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, if-statement, null

I have a class named Cell which derives from an Image.
I also have a Class named Field in which i have a Cell[][] named cells;

the problem is with checking if cells != null in MakeField().
the first call cells is null so no problem and all the cells get put in the array.
when calling MakeField() again cells is still equal to null and i can not see any values in debug, even though i can see them being set in the first call.

```
public class Field
{
    Cell[][] cells;

    public Field(byte fieldSize, GameObject prefab, GridLayoutGroup grid)
    {
        MakeField(fieldSize, prefab, grid);
    }

    public void MakeField(byte fieldSize, GameObject prefab, GridLayoutGroup grid)
    {
        if (cells != null)
            ClearField();

        cells = new Cell[fieldSize][];

        RectTransform rt = grid.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        ushort size = (ushort)(Math.Abs(rt.rect.width) / fieldSize - grid.spacing.x * (1 -  1 / fieldSize));
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(size, size);

        for (byte x = 0; x < fieldSize; x++)
        {
            cells[x] = new Cell[fieldSize];
            for (byte y = 0; y < fieldSize; y++)
            {
                cells[x][y] = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab, rt).GetComponent<Cell>();
            }
        }
    }

    public void ClearField()
    {
        Debug.Log("Clearing field");
        for (byte x = 0; x < cells.Length; x++)
            for (byte y = 0; y < cells[x].Length; y++)
                cells[x][y].DestroyCell();

        Array.Clear(cells, 0, cells.Length);
    }
}

public class Cell : Image
{
    byte x, y;
    ushort value;

    public Cell(byte x, byte y, ushort value)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        SetValue(value);
    }

    public void SetValue(ushort value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void DestroyCell()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

this is the array at the end of the first call
[image]

this is the array at the start of the second call
[image]

why is cells null?

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: The null reference seems to have magically solved it's self. now when debugging after setting the array 1 the first function call the second call field still starts as null.

Comment: how does the code look where you call the Method. I could think of you using new Field(4, 4, 10); so it create a new instance of the calss each time where the default value of cells is null.

Comment: I'm dealing with this VERY issue right now in a Unity project. My object most certainly isn't null, but returns true with `== null`. When is null not null? When it's not not null, or whatevery crazy ish this is.